# What's the best practise for storing web server credentials for your web app deployment?

Tags: web-applications, security, passwords

I was looking [at the Oracle documentation for the weblogic maven plugin.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13702/maven_deployer.htm)

In it, they store the weblogic user name and password for accessing in the pom.xml.

Just wondering, isn't this a terrible idea? How should one handle this?

```
 <plugin> 
      <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId> 
      <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
      <version>10.3.4</version> 
      <configuration> 
          <adminurl>t3://localhost:7001</adminurl>
          <user>weblogic</user> 
          <password>weblogic123</password> 
          <upload>true</upload> 
          <action>deploy</action> 
          <remote>false</remote> 
          <verbose>true</verbose> 
<source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source> 
         <name>${project.build.finalName}</name> 
      </configuration> 

      <executions> 
         <execution> 
            <phase>install</phase> 
              <goals> 
                <goal>deploy</goal> 
              </goals> 
         </execution> 
       </executions> 

  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 5):

This *is* a terrible idea if there are no clear warnings on the example page. It encourages developers to put their secrets in their configuration files on their developer machines. Those files end up in version control, which is very, very wrong.

The only location where configuration files might have secrets (see below about what I mean by secrets) is on strictly controlled production servers which can be accessed by trusted system administrators only. On developer machine, the same file may be presented as a template:

```xml
<configuration> 
    <adminurl>{{ADMIN_URL}}</adminurl>
    <user>{{ADMIN_USER}}</user> 
    <password>{{ADMIN_PASSWORD}}</password> 
    <upload>true</upload> 
    <action>deploy</action>
    ...
</configuration>
```

where the placeholders will be replaced by the actual values during the deployment (and can be replaced by different values during the local debugging).

The secrets themselves may be stored:

- In a separate version control,
- Which is encrypted,
- Which can be accessed only by the process which pushes the new revisions to production, as well as by the same system administrators who have a complete access to the servers anyway.

When deploying the revisions to production, a better option than using a template is to **put secrets in a completely separate file**. This file may be encrypted (with only the process¹ running the app being able to decrypt it), which means that developers may access the actual configuration (and see the value of the actual `adminurl` and `user` elements) for debugging purposes, without being able to access the secret itself.

**Secrets can also be stored in a database.** The benefits, compared to a simple file, are:

- The audit capability, that is the ability to track who accessed which secrets when.
- The fact that all the secrets are stored in the same central location, which makes it simple to manage security, to revoke permissions, to reset compromised secrets, etc.

The drawbacks are:

- The additional complexity, which may be too overwhelming for a small application (given that you need to deploy a separate virtual machine for the database, ensure it is protected, ensure logs and audit from this machine are sent to central logs server which is protected as well, etc.)
- The fact that all the secrets are stored in the same central location, which makes it a perfect target for an attacker (including a disgruntled employee.)

Note that:

- When I talk about secrets, I mean things like secret keys for the APIs. **The passwords of the actual users should never ever be stored**: the only thing which can be stored is a salted hash, never the plain password itself (nor the encrypted version of it). The term "password" used in the example is very misleading.
- `weblogic` is a terrible user name. Jeff Brown is a user. Cindy Coleman is a user. `admin` or `web` or `accounting` are not users, because they don't correspond to a single person. Such names encourage sharing the credentials among several persons (giving `root` password to all developers, including freelancers and interns, or `accounting` password to 5 accountants of the company, including the one who will be fired the next week), which is a terrible idea.
- Password `weblogic123` for the user `weblogic` sucks. Even as an example. The password `{b>\27P1.TrFM2WU@I5dc|` is a much better example.

---

<sup>¹ In Windows, this is possible by specifying the encryption property of the file: the decryption is done transparently for the application, so that the app doesn't have to deal with encryption keys (and the storage of the encryption keys). The same should be possible in other operating systems as well.</sup>

Comment: I think you're going a little off track with your last two bullet points. The passwords offered there are clearly placeholders for demonstration purposes.

Comment: The three bullet points are more comments/notes than a part of the answer, which explains their off-topic character. I find them still relevant, especially in a context where the discussed example could **easily** use *good* placeholders instead of bad ones.